# How to remove unknown characters using T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I try to do a script to eliminate the Chinese characters in a string and between the Chinese characters I want to remove. Please see the example below. Thank you.

```
select LTRIM(SUBSTRING('Tower 6A 第6A座', PATINDEX('%[a-zA-Z0-9]%', 'Tower 6A 第6A座'), LEN('Tower 6A 第6A座')))
select LTRIM(REPLACE(SUBSTRING('Tower 6A 第6A座', CHARINDEX(N'樓', 'Tower 6A 第6A座') + 1, LEN('Tower 6A 第6A座')), ' ', ''))
```

Sample string:

```
Tower 6A 第6A座
Tower 3 第3座
```

Bad Result:

```
Tower 6A ?6A?
Tower6A?6A?
Tower 3 ?3?
Tower3?3?
```

Good result, I want to achieve:

```
Tower 6A
Tower 6A
Tower 3
Tower 3
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
   SELECT Replace(Replace('Tower 6A 第6A座','[^a-zA-Z0-9]+', ''),'?','')
```

Comment: I upvoted this, but It will incorrectly remove valid (wanted) `?` characters from the fields.

Answer (score 2):

Looks weird but does the job. However I wouldn't count on great performance:

```
;WITH string AS (
    SELECT N'Tower 6A 第6A座' s
),
split AS (
    select LEFT(s, 1) s_item,
       STUFF(s, 1, 1, N'') s
    from string
    union all
    select LEFT(s, 1),
       STUFF(s, 1, 1, N'')
    from split
    where s > ''
)
,
remove_non_ascii AS ( 
    SELECT s_item, UNICODE(s_item) s_unicode
    FROM split WHERE UNICODE(s_item)<256
)
SELECT STUFF((SELECT s_item FROM remove_non_ascii
FOR XML PATH, TYPE).value('.[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1,0, '');
```

What it does:

1. Splits strings into rows
2. Eliminates UNICODE characters bigger than 256 (you can fiddle with condition)
3. Puts the string together

It uses recursive query so in case of strings longer than 100 characters you need to expand amount of recursive loops by adding: `OPTION (MAXRECURSION n)` (where n is new amount of recursive loops)

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
;With cte(Data)
AS
(
SELECT 'Tower 6A 第6A座' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Tower 3 第3座'
)
SELECT
CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('Tower', DATA)= 0 THEN 'Tower ' + DATA ELSE DATA END AS DATA
FROM
(
SELECT
Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(1000)') AS Data
FROM
(
SELECT  CAST('<S>' + REPLACE(REPLACE(Data, '?', '</S><S>'),'','</S><S>') + '</S>' AS XML) AS Data
FROM cte
) AS 
    A CROSS APPLY Data.nodes('/S') AS Split(a)
) DT
Where
DT.Data <> ''
```

Result

```
DATA
----------
Tower 6A 
Tower 6A
Tower 3 
Tower 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [delimitedSplit8k](https://www.google.com/search?q=delimitedsplit8k&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS750US750&oq=del&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0l3j69i65l2.751j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) you can do this:

```
-- Sample data
DECLARE @table TABLE (someid int identity, string nvarchar(100));
INSERT @table VALUES (N'Tower 6A 第6A座'), (N'Tower 3 第3座');

-- Solution
WITH base AS
(
  SELECT someid, ItemNumber, itemClean = replace(item,'?','')
  FROM @table t
  CROSS APPLY dbo.delimitedSplit8K(t.string, ' ')
)
SELECT someid, newstring = b1.itemClean + ' ' +  b2.itemClean
FROM base b1
CROSS APPLY 
(
  SELECT itemClean 
  FROM base b2 WHERE ItemNumber = 1 AND b1.someid = b2.someid
) b2
WHERE b1.ItemNumber > 1;
```

Results:

```
someid      newstring
----------- ---------
1           6A Tower
1           6A Tower
2           3 Tower
2           3 Tower
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach for this problem is to make use of SQL Server 2016 ability to execute R Script. For this method to work you will have to ensure that the R Services has been installed on your SQL Server, you will also have to enable the ‘sp_execute_external_script’ stored procedure.
Enable external scripts as follow:

```
EXECUTE sp_configure;
GO
-- enable execution of external script add an argument:
EXECUTE sp_configure 'external scripts enabled', 1;
GO

RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

Also ensure that the ‘SQL Server Launchpad’ service is running.  You may also have to restart SQL Server.

If we convert our input data containing the Chinese characters from a Unicode to ASCII (VARCHAR) then SQL Server will automatically convert the Chinese characters to question marks ‘?’.
Next, we can use the R languages pattern matching capabilities to remove all the text between the question marks (formally our Chinese characters) as per following example:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[ExampleData]') AND type in (N'U'))
BEGIN

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ExampleData](
        [RawData] [nvarchar](100) NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

    INSERT INTO ExampleData
    (
        [RawData]
    )
    VALUES ( N'Tower 6A 第6A座');

    INSERT INTO ExampleData
    (
        [RawData]
    )
    VALUES ( N'Tower 3 第3座');

END

DECLARE @inputQuery NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT CAST([RawData] AS VARCHAR(100)) as a FROM ExampleData'

DECLARE @RScript NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'
pattern <-"\\?.*\\?";
inData$a <- sub(pattern, "\\1", inData$a, perl = T );
outData <- inData;';


EXEC sp_execute_external_script @language = N'R'
, @script = @RScript
, @input_data_1 = @inputQuery
, @input_data_1_name = N'inData'
, @output_data_1_name=N'outData'
with result sets ( (a varchar(300)));
```